# Could not make parent directory for itmtransporter

Tags: ios, objective-c, deployment

I am having this issue when I am trying to upload my app via xcode 7.1 or Application loader. Can any one help ?

[image]

> Could not make parent directory for:
>   /Users/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Resources/ITunesSoftwareServiceConfiguration.xml
>
> An exception has occurred:
>   /Users/.itmstransporter/softwaresupport/bin/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Resources/ITunesSoftwareServiceConfiguration.xml
>   (No such file or directory)
>
> Could not configure software support.

Answer (score 6):

1. cd ~/.itmstransporter
2. rm update_check*
3. mv softwaresupport softwaresupport.bak
4. cd UploadTokens
5. rm *.token

This is the correct Fix for the problem above. Thanks :) Happy Coding

Comment: Unfortunately that procedure did not fix my problems, I still get:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter: line 171: [: Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/rt.jar: integer expression expected

Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file <Zip file open error> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application Loader.app/Contents/itms/java/lib/rt.jar
Should I archive again after having performed the procedure?

Comment: Your issue is different them mine error. you have following reason of error "error in opening JAR file"

Comment: The thing is very shaky. My present situation is Client Error 3000 when submitting from Xcode. And apparently no problem by submitting with Application Loader. Yet, the latest time I did it I was reported the build was already there, so in some way a binary got through somehow.

Comment: 3000 Error is temporary apple server error, wait for some hours and re-upload or make a new provisioning profile it will fix error. the reason is apple is really facing troubles these days and their server and support is very bad some how that is why most developers are facing severe issues.